# Initializing undefined namespace

Tags: php, namespaces

I'm working on a big project with many functionalities.  One of these functionalities is defined into a namespace.

My problem began when I wanted to initialize a class which is not defined into the namespace. This class isn't defined in any namespace, is just a class into the whole project.

The error,

> Fatal error: Class ... not found ...

I tried to include this file, but is not working.

So I have:

```
namespace apps\aaa;

    use apps\aaa\bbb;
    use apps\cccc\ddd\eee;

class xxx
{
   // I tryed to use include_once with the path of the file but doesn't work.
   // and in some place into the class, I want to initialize this "unnamedspace class".
   $some_var= new unnamedsapceclass();
}
```

So, how should I work with it?

Comment: Try to use `$some_var = new \unnamedsapceclass();`.  (Notice the slash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A class with no namespace defined belongs to the root namespace, you can specify it by prepending a namespace separator:

```
$some_var= new \unnamedsapceclass();
```

Answer (score 0):

Namespaces are completely optional. If you don't want a namespace, define your class without a namespace.

If PHP can't find the class it simply hasn't been defined. Check if the right files are being included.